# Crop images from Layers in PSD file

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I have a PSD file which contains many Layers and each layer contains either some image or text. I want to get/extract in a combined form e.g. one text layer and one image layer combined. Can any one help me how can I crop images from layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LAYERS panel,
Select a TEXT layer by clicking it. and While holding ctrl(cmd for mac) key, select the related IMAGE layer.
Now, Press, ctrl+E(cmd+E for mac) to merge both layers.
You've to repeat this process for each combination of TEXT and IMAGE.

Once you're done with that, 
File -> Scripts -> Export Layers to Files...
Select the desired Destination to save layers as image, select the file type you want. 
Now  click Run and wait for photoshop to automate the process.

You'll have all layers saved as image in the destination path.